# How can I use request.get with paramerer instead of full path

Tags: python, request, get

I have a page from which I would like to get data and sample request call  e.g. [http://smepage.com?select="name","numer"&where=number="10"](http://smepage.com?select=%22name%22,%22numer%22&where=number=%2210%22)

To get the data I use python requests and it works:

```
URL=http://somepage.com?select="name","numer"&where=number="10"
requests.get(URL)
```

But is it possible to use dict or some other container to pass parameters?
I tried to use json but it did not work

```
params = {
"select":["name","numer"],
"where": {"number":"5"}
}
URL=http://somepage.com
requests.get(URL, json=params)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have has part of your query `?select="name","numer"`. This passes a single value as the `select` parameter, namely the string `'"name","numer"'`. Yet in your `params` dictionary you have for the `select` parameter `["name", "numer"]`, which would be passing a list of two values as if you had specified `?select=name&select=numer`. So it's not clear what it is you really wish to pass. But if I go by your original URL, then:

```py
params = {"select": '"name","numer"', "where": 'number="10"'}
url = "http://somepage.com"
# params=params, not json=params:
response = requests.get(url, params=params)
print(response.text)
```

**You need to specify for `params` a dictionary whose keys are the parameter names and whose values are either a string or list of strings and then pass this dictionary to `get` as the *params* argument.**

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the query parameters using the named argument `params` in the `requests.get` call.

This code should do what you want.

```
import requests


params = {"select": ["name", "numer"], "where": {"number": "5"}}
url = "http://somepage.com"
response = requests.get(url, params=params)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Your `params` dictionary would be the equivalent of the OP having specified `?select=name&select=numer&where=number`, which is not at all what the OP specified.